# Printing both double sided and single sided with the same .cmd scipt

Tags: pdf, cmd, printing, duplex

I am having a problem which I can't solve for the last few days now.
I have a lot of .pdf files in different folders which I want to print at the same time, without opening each one and print them individually.
The situation is as follows:
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup1/CustomerA/OrderCustomerA.pdf
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup1/CustomerA/OrderCustomerAPart2.pdf
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup1/CustomerB/OrderCustomerB.pdf
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup2/CustomerC/OrderCustomerC.pdf

*And this goes on, but you get the point (I hope :D)*

I wrote the following .cmd script to sent all these files to the printer:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /h /t "G:\General\Orders\2020\2020June\CustomerGroup1/CustomerA\OrderCustomerA.pdf" "\\PRINTER NAME "nul"
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /h /t "G:\General\Orders\2020\2020June\CustomerGroup1/CustomerA\OrderCustomerAPart2.pdf" "\\PRINTER NAME "nul"
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /h /t "G:\General\Orders\2020\2020June\CustomerGroup1/CustomerB\OrderCustomerB.pdf" "\\PRINTER NAME "nul"
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /h /t "G:\General\Orders\2020\2020June\CustomerGroup2/CustomerC\OrderCustomerC.pdf" "\\PRINTER NAME "nul"
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
*(and so on)*

PAUSE
```

*(The 5 second break between each line is needed because otherwise the printer cannot handle the speed of the receiving files)*

This script works and sends all the files to the printer, but it listens to the default settings of the printer. So if the printers default setting is to print double sided, every file is printed double sided. If I change the printers default setting to print one-sided, every file is printed one sided.

So my question is:
Is is possible to add a command after each line to tell the printer if this file needs to be printed double-sided or one-sided?

So lets say I want it like this:
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup1/CustomerA/OrderCustomerA.pdf **DOUBLE-SIDED**
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup1/CustomerA/OrderCustomerAPart2.pdf **DOUBLE-SIDED**
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup1/CustomerB/OrderCustomerB.pdf **ONE-SIDED**
G:/General/Orders/2020/2020June/CustomerGroup2/CustomerC/OrderCustomerC.pdf **DOUBLE-SIDED**

I tried so many different things the last days and looked around different forums but I could not find an answer. So I hope somebody can help me. I hope everything is explained clearly. If not, please let me know. :)

Comment: Duplicate the printer on the Windows computer used for printing the PDF files. Configure for one printer to print by default single sided and configure for the other printer to print by default double sided to same physical printer. Then use the appropriate printer name to print on same physical printer a file either single or double sided. There is no possibility to change printer options after the printer received already the data for printing. Adobe Reader has no option to control single or double side printing as far as I know if the printer supports double side printing at all.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you so much, this makes my life a lot easier :)